# Java - How to extend the ArrayList<class> ? I can't get my defined getter

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

I would like extend the ArrayList<> Class

As you can see in the example below, I have only added one attribute (TypeFactory).

```
public class ElementList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
{
    // Attribute
    private TypeFactory typeFactory;

    // Getter/Setter
    public TypeFactory getTypeFactory() {
        return typeFactory;
    }

    public void setTypeFactory(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        this.typeFactory = typeFactory;
    }

    // Constructor
    public ElementList(TypeFactory typeFactory)
    {
        super();
        this.typeFactory = typeFactory;
    }
}
```

My problem is that my IDE (in my case IntelliJ) don't find the getTypeFactory() getter method and appears in red text (as an error) after creating a new ElementList object.

```
List<Element> stockOfTire = new ElementList<Element>(TypeFactory.Tire);
stockOfTire.getTypeFactory();
```

Is there a problem with my declaration ?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to do this? [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). _Compose_ data, _inherit_ behaviour.

Comment: The `stockOfTire` variable's type is List<Element>. There is no getTypeFactory() existing on this type. If you need to access this method, the variable must be declared with the type ElementList<Element>. Note that extending ArrayList, in 99.99% of the cases, is a bad idea. Consider creating a class with a TypeFactory and a List fields, instead, and to delegate to the wrapped list.

Comment: I don't understand why I can do `List<class> var = new ArrayList<class>();` and why it doesn't work when replacing **ArrayList** by a daughter Class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `List<Element>` does not have such a function, only `ElementList<Element>` has. Change your code to:

```
ElementList<Element> stockOfTire = new ElementList<Element>(TypeFactory.Tire);
stockOfTire.getTypeFactory();
```